# OFET vs Traditional Transistors

Tags: physical-chemistry, materials

What is the advance of OFET's (Organic Field effect transistors) over the traditional CMOS Transistors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The advantages of OFET's over traditional CMOS transistors all derive from how OFET's can be manufactured.  Traditional transistors are manufactured using **vacuum deposition** techniques.  These are slow, time consuming, batch processes, hence the higher cost for electronic components produced by such methods.

OFET's can be manufactured using standard **coating** technologies that have been widely used in industry for a long time, and are well understood.  Therefore, the manufacturing equipment needed is readily available. With this coating equipment uniform layers ranging from sub-micron to tens of microns (you don't need thicker layers for an OFET, but the coating technology would allow you to coat much thicker layers if you wanted to) can be coated at high speed on thin, flexible, web supports such as aluminized mylar. Multiple layers can be coated by making multiple passes down the coating line, into a drying oven and then on to the next coater.  Thousands of OFETS can be obtained from a small, coated, mylar spool. Since the process is continuous and high speed the manufacturing cost of the device is much reduced compared to similar CMOS devices.  Each layer contains an active organic compound dissolved in a low-cost plastic (for example, polycarbonate) binder, so material costs are reduced as well.  Another key advantage is that since organic materials, plastic binders and flexible web materials are used, the final product is flexible and can be easily cut to any desired shape.  This allows the manufacturer to use the product in new applications where flexibility (newspapers) and shape (electronic clocks) might preclude the use of rigid CMOS devices.